How do I set values on multiple child elements (stimulus)
I have a parent element with two inner elements:
<div data-controller="text">
  <p id="child1" data-text-max-length-value="100" contenteditable=true>
    Some text
  </p>
  <p id="child2" data-text-max-length-value="200" contenteditable=true>
    Some text
  </p>
</div>

Each child element sets a value. My understanding is the value should be assigned to its specific element. In my controller, however, the element is being identified as the outer div and the maxLength value is reading the default value.
export default class extends Controller {
  static values = {
    originalFontSize: String,
    maxLength: Number
  }

  limitLength() {
    console.log(this.element, this.maxLengthValue)
  }
 }


As you can see, I can access the element through event.target. Through that, I can find event.target.dataset.textMaxLengthValue. Is there a way to do this with stimulus though, and not just vanilla js? Or is it not possible for the same value to be set on multiple child elements. And why is this.element returning the parent instead of the child?
Edit: I can't use targets in this scenario because the functions are meant to be used dynamically on any target

value attributes are only for data-controller element. for this case, you can use any data attribute and read it directly from dataset.

So to rephrase, the value only gets set on the outer element? Child elements can't have their own value? I am using dataset for now

correct. values are for your controller. i don't if it works for you but there are also params for actions https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/actions#action-parameters
